# How to implement AATL/EUTL signing certs delivered on secure USB token in a hosted VM environment

Tags: pdf, x509certificate, aatl

We are generating document PDF's as part of our server application workflow.  We need to be able to sign these documents to prove they are from us and have not been tampered with.  We currently do this using a self-signed cert and using [syncfusion's PDF module](https://www.syncfusion.com/pdf-framework/net) (excellent sw btw!).  The problem is (of course) that the self-signed cert is not in the CA trust chain so although the document is secured, it doesnt automatically validate that its from us.

I have been researching where to purchase AATL certified certificates from and have found several vendors ([Identrust](https://www.identrust.com/certificates/document-signing) being one of the more affordable options).  However, they all share the same delivery method which is they ship it to you on a secure USB or similar token.  What I dont understand then is how to use this token with our hosted VM.  Does anyone have any experience in using these types of token ie. are we simply able to export the private key from the token onto the server?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use the tokens in this scenario.

The certificate issuer should provide you with a web-based API that you integrate in your signing process. Usually you send the document hash and get back the signature, but the actual flow and ins/outs depends on the certificate provider.
Then the PDF library you use should let you embed in the PDF file the externally computed signature.

Comment: Thank you.  That makes perfect sense to me, so now I just need to find a provider of signing services.

Comment: GlobalSign is an option

Comment: I've just them an information request as there's not much information on their website.  I still can't understand why its so hard to get clear answers from Adobe on this.  I dont expect I'm any different from any modern company that generates proposals, quotes etc in the cloud and wants to protect them through certificates.